# How to convert character array into list in kdb

Tags: kdb, q-lang

We have KDB query which sources data from different columns and one of the columns has Character array type ('C'), i.e. it contains text. 
What we want is `enlist` it when we query for data like this
`select enlist column_with_character_arr from table`

i.e. to have ("value1") inside a list so we will be able to add one more element to this list later on, say, ("value1", "value2"). How to do it? Because currently when we try to `enlist` or add `,()` it fails with length error.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are missing `each` here. Use:

```
select enlist each column_with_character_arr from table
```

ex:

```
q) t:([]v:("abc";"xyz"))
q) select enlist each v from t
```

**Why length error on select (),v from t?**

Because comma(`,`) in select query separates different columns we want in output, i.e.

```
select col1,col2 from tbl
```

So in query : `select (),v from t`: first column (before comma) has no value and second column is `v` and hence count of both columns are different. That's why it gives `` `length `` error.

To make it run, use:

```
q) select ((),v) from t
```

But this will not enlist  each item of `v`. It's just appending null to `v` column.